Ubuntu LXDE 20.04 failing to draw some user interfaces ( buttons, menus, tooltips, etc )
Desktop with LXDE (LUbuntu 20.04), on an I5 10400, Intel® UHD Graphics 630, drivers/modinfo at the end of  the post.
Based on Lubuntu pages, it uses XOrg, not Wayland.
OS is failing to draw some kind of user interfaces, like menus, tooltips, buttons, etc, as shown in pics below. It's kind of  failing letters or backgrounds before all the UI widget is completely drawn.
How to fix it?
menu  on VirtualBox:

tooltip on stackexchage.com upper right icon:

Driver information:
-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Modinfo:
filename:      
/lib/modules/5.4.0-193-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights description:    Intel
Graphics author:         Intel Corporation author:         Tungsten
Graphics, Inc. firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin firmware:     
i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin firmware:       i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
firmware:       i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin firmware:      
i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin firmware:       i915/icl_dmc_ver1_07.bin
firmware:       i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin firmware:      
i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin firmware:       i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin
firmware:       i915/bxt_huc_ver01_8_2893.bin firmware:      
i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin firmware:       i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin firmware:      
i915/glk_huc_ver03_01_2893.bin firmware:       i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin firmware:      
i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin firmware:       i915/icl_huc_ver8_4_3238.bin
firmware:       i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin


It's likely that you might be running Wayland on currently unsupported hardware, and I'd ask you to also add your graphics card & driver info to your posts about graphical issues. Log out of your session, and in the desktop manager/login screen click the cogwheel and select GNOME on Xorg.

I edited the previous post to add infos you mention. Important to note, and I forgot to mention in the previous post, I'm running LXDE.
